# rails form add fields dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set a set of fields to be dynamically displayed on demand. In the model, I've the fields:

```
attr_accessible ... :instruct1, :instruct2, ... :instruct30
```

I would like the form to display just instruct1 with a button to add 1 more field until instruct30 is hit and a button to remove one until instruct 1 is hit. All should happen without refreshing page which i think would include some use of AJAX but I couldn't find anything that is similar.

I've searched for something similar but only able to come up with nested form which is not what im looking for as my model is fixed.

Comment: I think you would find what you're looking for if you establish two models -- whatever this model is, and a model for Instruction.  The two are related in a simple `has_many` and `belongs_to`.  In this way each of your base model will have a collection of Instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The majority of your work is going to be on the client side.

To add and remove form fields dynamically, you have to use javascript.
Check out the HTML that Rails generates for the first field, replicate that and add the additional fields using for example jQuery.

A crude example:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#theForm")
    .append('<input id="instruct2" name="object[instruct2]" type="text">');
});
```

You'd have to keep track of how many fields you've added or removed.