# Add Dynamic fields in a form with a plus symbol in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to add fields dynamically in a form using html/css/javascript/jquery and would like it to be stored properly in Rails.

[image]

How would I go about it in?

I have tried to check these links: [rails form add fields dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277204/rails-form-add-fields-dynamically)

but they only show the front-end side.

Comment: Have you already given a try to `nathanvda/cocoon` gem?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did it for me. Thanks